# Expo App.json. Add permissions with options (maxSdk, useSdk)

Tags: expo

### The problem:

But there are changes on Android Permissions that needs to specify different permissions for different SDKs. Example: [Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions)

See bluetooth example on bottom.

### How it works now on App.json example

On App Expo [App.json Permission](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions) i can only add a direct permission that will work with every version of Android.

### What i want to do

But i want to do it using Expo workflow, setting on App.json and automatic generating the Android Manifest. But i don´t know how to add extra options like `maxSdk: 30`.

### Current workaround

I can set manually the permissions on generated file. And it works. But on a new project prebuild, it can be overriden and i need to re-edit the file.

```xml
<manifest>
    <!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices.
         If your app doesn't use Bluetooth scan results to derive physical
         location information, you can strongly assert that your app
         doesn't derive physical location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth
         devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
         devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <!-- Needed only if your app uses Bluetooth scan results to derive physical location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you manage to have a workaround? How about Expo custom plugins, which can perhaps add entry of 'maxSdkVersion' to that permission entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so figured out a workaround utilizing [Expo Config-plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/).

Foremost, on your [Expo config / app.config.js](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v48.0.0/config/app/); on the android part, you can add in the new permissions required for Android API 31+:

`permissions: ["BLUETOOTH", "BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"]`

This seems to work fine for me.

For the legacy support, or if you've had issues [like me] where your App crashes if legacy Bluetooth is added even along the new BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, for example, use this config plugin.

Create a new file called: withModifyBluetoothPermission.js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const config_plugins_1 = require("@expo/config-plugins");
const withModifyBluetoothPermission = (config) => {
    return (0, config_plugins_1.withAndroidManifest)(config, (config) => {
        config.modResults = withModifyBluetoothPlatform(config.modResults);
        return config;
    });
};
function withModifyBluetoothPlatform(androidManifest) {
    if (!Array.isArray(androidManifest.manifest["uses-permission"])) {
        androidManifest.manifest["uses-permission"] = [];
    }
    if (androidManifest.manifest["uses-permission"].find((item) => item.$["android:name"] === "android.permission.BLUETOOTH")) {
        config_plugins_1.AndroidConfig.Manifest.ensureToolsAvailable(androidManifest);
        androidManifest.manifest["uses-permission"] = androidManifest.manifest["uses-permission"].filter((item) => item.$["android:name"] !== "android.permission.BLUETOOTH");
        androidManifest.manifest["uses-permission"]?.push({
            $: {
                "android:name": "android.permission.BLUETOOTH",
                "android:maxSdkVersion": "30",
            },
        });
    }
    return androidManifest;
}
exports.default = withModifyBluetoothPermission;
```

Once created, add it on your [Expo Config / app.config.js](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v48.0.0/config/app/), like:

```
plugins: [
 ["./config_plugins/withModifyBluetoothPermission"],
]
```

Do note that I'm only modifying BLUETOOTH to have the required maxSdk option, for the rest, perhaps you can modify them to your liking based on the config-plugin above.

Comment: This solves the problem. By making a custom override for the permissions, i can regenerate the gradle file and compile without manual editing.